# Cant regex for '<3'

Tags: python, regex

Been trying for a while with this regex down below, can some one please tell me what I am wrong.

Python script

```
msg = 'Hello <3'
print msg
print re.findall('/\<3/', msg)
```

Output

```
Hello <3
[]
```

Comment: `<3` is a literal string and does not need to be escaped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need the `/` delimiters in Python. You also do not need to escape the `<`.

```
import re

msg = 'Hello <3'
print msg
print re.findall('<3', msg)
```

Output:

```
['<3']
```

Comment: Wow, really that was it.. Feel so stupid now! Thank you man! :) (old php:er here)

Comment: @ViktorGardart, It's quite understandable. Sometimes I wish all languages handled string searching and regexes in the same way.